# Why am I seeing docker.io infront of the docker images repository name?

Tags: docker, centos7

strong text[image]

Listing the docker images shows the images with prefix docker.io which is weird as I haven't seen like this in my previous installation. What is this mean? How to remove it?
I have installed docker on CentOS. My previous installation was on Ubuntu where it worked perfectly.

Comment: I guess that you have a non default Registry in `docker info`. Doesn't it?

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -qa | grep docker` ?